# PDF viewer for tcl

Tags: pdf, tcl

Does a pdf-viewer plugin exist already for tcl ? If not, is there a way I could go about building a document viewer that could be embedded into my tcl GUI ?

I'm not really sure where to start so I'd appreciate any help on the same. Thanks.

Comment: You could try converting the PDF to bitmaps and showing them in a canvas: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/pdf-preview-for-tcl-tk-4175463174/

Comment: I'm guessing something with embedding ghostscript might work.

Comment: May be http://wiki.tcl.tk/19851 — Unfortunately, it seems dead and I could not get an older version on web archive sites :(